# Disable argparse choices message

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

`Argparse` displays message about the list of choices, like in this example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--styles', choices=long_list_of_styles)
```

As I'm passing a long list, help message does not look good, in fact it looks confusing and it shadows other arguments by its presence, because of all those choices being printed.

Is there any way to tell `Argparser` not to print arguments choices?

Comment: This was already asked before. You have to use a custom help formatter as shown in the linked question.

Comment: Thanks I did not get any results with Google. However both solutions in linked answer are too complicated. I'll just remove choices.

Comment: My suggestion: don't use `choices` and manually check if the option given is a choice. Provide an option like `--help-styles` that will print the list of names of available styles, so that users can still access the list of supported choices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proposed duplicate, [Python's argparse choices constrained printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272806/pythons-argparse-choices-constrained-printing)
presents a relatively complicated solution - a custom `HelpFormatter`.  Or a custom `type`.

A higher vote question/answers is [Python argparse: Lots of choices results in ugly help output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366369/python-argparse-lots-of-choices-results-in-ugly-help-output)

You'll find more with a `[argparse] choices` search.

The simplest solution is to set the `metavar` parameter.  `None` displays nothing in the `choices` slot, but you probably want a short word

```
In [8]: styles=['one','two','three','four']
In [10]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [11]: parser.add_argument('--styles', metavar='STYLE', choices=styles,
    ...:    help='list of choices: {%(choices)s}')
Out[11]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--styles'], dest='styles', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], help='list of choices: {%(choices)s}', metavar='STYLE')

In [12]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--styles STYLE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  --styles STYLE  list of choices: {one, two, three, four}
```

I included `%(choices)s` in the help to list them there. You could of course put your own summary there.  A long list fits better there than in `usage`.

Comment: Given that you have found this answer on an other duplicate you should have reopened the question *and closed it as a duplicate of the other one* instead of re-duplicating that again...